# How to cd to a directory with spaces in the directory name?

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm using Bash on macOS X and I'd like to create a simple executable script file that would change to another directory when it's run.  However, the path to that directory has spaces in it.  How the heck do you do this?  This is what I have...

Name of file: `cdcode`

File contents:

```
cd ~/My Code
```

Now granted, this isn't a long pathname, but my actual pathname is five directories deep and four of those directories have spaces in the path.

BTW, I've tried `cd "~/My Code"` and `cd "~/My\ Code"` and neither of these worked.

Comment: I am having a similar problem as the one described. 

I.e. none of the possible ways to change to a directory wich has a space in it. 

Nothing like :

cd "My Passport"
cd My\ Passport
cd My" Passport"

nothing is working.
The complition works fine. 
I can list :
ls -l My\ Passport/

works fine.

\>uname -a
Linux host 2.6.18-8.1.8.el5.centos.plus #1 SMP Mon Jul 16 08:49:50 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

\>bash --help
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release-(i686-redhat-linux-gnu)

any ideas please?

Answer (score 107):

When you double-quote a path, you're stopping the tilde expansion. So there are a few ways to do this:

```
cd ~/"My Code"
cd ~/'My Code'
```

The tilde is not quoted here, so tilde expansion will still be run.

```
cd "$HOME/My Code"
```

You can expand environment variables inside double-quoted strings; this is basically what the tilde expansion is doing

```
cd ~/My\ Code
```

You can also escape special characters (such as space) with a backslash.

Comment: You could even cd ~/My' 'Code, but that would be silly when you can escape it with a backslash instead

Comment: The right answer. Questioner needs to choose it.

Answer (score 50):

I found the solution below on [this page](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/can_my_path_include_directory_names_with_spaces.html):

```
x="test\ me"  
eval cd $x
```

A combination of `\` in a double-quoted text constant and an `eval` before `cd` makes it work like a charm!

Comment: more clarity: For cd'ing to the directory of a file of a script:  
DIR = $(dirname "$0");
eval cd $DIR

Comment: This really helped for me running a bash-script on a OS X machine. 

Comment: There is really no need for `eval` here.

Comment: On OS X, I couldn't get the other/prior answers to work without `eval`.

Answer (score 22):

After struggling with the same problem, I tried two different solutions that works:

### 1. Use double quotes (`""`) with your variables.

Easiest way just double quotes your variables as pointed in previous answer:

```
cd "$yourPathWithBlankSpace"
```

### 2. Make use of `eval`.

According to this answer [Unix command to escape spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806987/unix-command-to-escape-spaces) you can strip blank space then make use of `eval`, like this:

```
yourPathEscaped=$(printf %q "$yourPathWithBlankSpace")
eval cd $yourPathEscaped
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use any of:

```
cd ~/"My Code"
cd ~/M"y Code"
cd ~/My" Code"
```

You cannot use:

```
cd ~"/My Code"
```

The first works because the shell expands ~/ into $HOME/, and then tacks on My Code without the double quotes.  The second fails because there isn't a user called '`"`' (double quote) for `~"` to map to.

Answer (score 10):

```
cd ~/My\ Code
```

seems to work for me... If dropping the quotes but keeping the slash doesn't work, can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 7):

This will do it:

```
cd ~/My\ Code
```

I've had to use that to work with files stored in the iCloud Drive. You won't want to use double quotes (") as then it must be an absolute path. In other words, you can't combine double quotes with tilde (~).

By way of example I had to use this for a recent project:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Documents\ -\ My\ iMac/Project
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

A single backslash works for me:

```
ry4an@ry4an-mini:~$ mkdir "My Code"

ry4an@ry4an-mini:~$ vi todir.sh

ry4an@ry4an-mini:~$ . todir.sh 

ry4an@ry4an-mini:My Code$ cat ../todir.sh 
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/My\ Code
```

Are you sure the problem isn't that your shell script is changing directory in its subshell, but then you're back in the main shell (and original dir) when done?  I avoided that by using . to run the script in the current shell, though most folks would just use an alias for this.  The spaces could be a red herring.

Comment: Thanks, Ry4an (and the rest of the respondents).  It seems that I was executing the script incorrectly.  I was just trying to run it like so:

% ./cdsomedir

I didn't realize I needed to use the "." to run the script as you did:

% . cdsomedir.sh

Once I did that, it worked.  Newbie mistake. Thanks!

Comment: The `#!/bin/sh` line does not do anything useful with a file which you need to invoke with `.` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When working under Linux the syntax below is right:

`cd ~/My\ Code`

However when you're executing your file, use the syntax below:

`$ . cdcode`

(just '.' and not './')

Comment: Out of wild curiosity, why does that matter?  I've only ever seen './' useed.

Comment: ./ will spawn a new shell, and then change the directory. So when the script exits, it goes back to the shell which spawned the new shell... you'll be in the directory where you executed the script instead of ~/My Code.

 '.' on the other hand causes the script to be executed in the current instance of the shell.

Comment: The dot "." is a unix command, an alias for the "source" command.

It should be followed by a filename. 
So "source myfile" will run the file within your current shell.
And ". myfile" will do the same.

The "./" variable means "current directory" and is not a command.

Answer (score 2):

use double quotes

```
go () 
{ 
    cd "$*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A useful addition to the functions in a `.bashrc` file for changing directory when pasting directory names containing spaces on to the command line without having to then escape the spaces or quote the whole thing. `cds` is a better name though.

Comment: Is there any way to extend this (without an if) such that just `go` will be equivalent to `cd`, i.e., cd to home directory?

Answer (score 2):

The very simple way of doing this is-

```
 $ cd My\ Folder
```

In bash, run DIR command and in the results you would see that the folder or path names having space between them has been written in the results like this -

```
$dir
My\ Folder
New\ Folder
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes, like:

```
myPath=~/'my dir'

cd $myPath
```

Answer (score 2):

I read all these, and they didn't seem to work on macOS Monterey. I then changed the header from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/zsh`and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid ~ in scripts; use $HOME instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem now were I was using a bash script to dump some data. I ended up creating a symbolic link in the script folder with out any spaces in it. I then pointed my script to the symbolic link and that works fine.

To create your link.
ln -s [TARGET DIRECTORY OR FILE] ./[SHORTCUT]

Mau or may not be of use.