# Unix command to escape spaces

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to shell script. Can someone help me with command to escape the space with "\ ".
I have a variable FILE_PATH=/path/to my/text file ,
I want to escape the spaces alone
FILE_PATH=/path/to\ my/text\ file

I tried with tr -s command but it doesnt help

FILE_PATH=`echo FILE_PATH | tr -s " " "\\ "`

Can somebody suggest the right command !!

Comment: What is the **real** problem you're having?

Comment: Just want to escape the space so that I can use in other commands like cp , rm , etc

Comment: If you want to use FILE_PATH in other commands, just use quotes.  `rm "$FILE_PATH"` works just fine if it contains whitespace.

Comment: Note: the `-s` stands for squeeze not substitute. Squeeze consecutive spaces into one space. Also, `tr` only replaces 1 for 1, not a space with both a backslash and space.

Answer (score 64):

If you are using bash, you can use its builtin printf's %q formatter (type `help printf` in bash):

```
FILENAME=$(printf %q "$FILENAME")
```

This will not only quote space, but also all special characters for shell.

Comment: Using this I still having problems with two concatenate spaces. What can I do?

Comment: This seems ok in zsh too.

Answer (score 13):

There's more to making a string safe than just escaping spaces, but you can escape the spaces with:

```
FILE_PATH=$( echo "$FILE_PATH" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' )
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I'm guessing that you're suggesting elimination of characters reserved by the shell, e.g., `[ ] ( ) { } ; ' " [:space:] &` as well as non-printable characters. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: @Barton It will certainly depend on use, but all of the characters you mention are suspect.  Mostly what I have in mind is that attempting to escape characters for any sort of protection is fragile and not something that should be done without great care.

Answer (score 9):

You can use '*single quotes*' to operate on a path that contains spaces:

`cp '/path/with spaces/file.txt' '/another/spacey path/dir'`

`grep foo '/my/super spacey/path with spaces/folder/*'`

in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

spacey_dir='My Documents'
spacey_file='Hello World.txt'
mkdir '$spacey_dir'
touch '${spacey_dir}/${spacey_file}'
```

Comment: Unless you need to do variable interpolation, I would actually suggest using single quotes rather than double. There are some sneaky characters such as `!` which bash will try to interpolate inside double quotes, but not single. Of course, you are free to cast a pox on anyone who puts bang characters in file names.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `sed` :

```
NEW_FILE_PATH="$(echo $FILE_PATH | sed 's/ /\\\ /g')"
```

Comment: `FILE_PATH=$(echo $FILE_PATH | sed "s/ /\\\ /g")`

You need three backslashes because you have to escape the backslash character both in the shell and in sed.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes to preserve the SPACE character

tr is used only for replacing individual characters 1 for 1. Seems to be that you need sed.

```
echo $FILE_PATH | sed -e 's/ /\\ /'
```

seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to use **eval** when using printf guarding.

Here's a sample from Codegen Script under Build Phases of Xcode (somehow PROJECT_DIR is not guarded of spaces, so build was failing if you have a path with spaces):

```
PROJECT_DIR_GUARDED=$(printf %q "$PROJECT_DIR")
eval $PROJECT_DIR_GUARDED/scripts/code_gen.sh $PROJECT_DIR_GUARDED
```

Answer (score -4):

```
FILE_PATH=/path/to my/text file
FILE_PATH=echo FILE_PATH | tr -s " " "\\ "
```

That second line needs to be

```
FILE_PATH=echo $FILE_PATH | tr -s " " "\\ "
```

**but I don't think it matters.  Once you have reached this stage, you are too late.  The variable has been set, and either the spaces are escaped or the variable is incorrect.**

FILE_PATH='/path/to my/text file'

Comment: `FILE_PATH=echo $FILE_PATH | tr -s " " "\\ "` is broken. You need `$( )`

Comment: Fair enough -- I was typing quickly -- but that wasn't the primary point.

Comment: Also, `tr` cannot be used for this.