# How to read input with spaces in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

This is my shell script,which needs to execute any type of command same as terminal,

```
#!/bin/sh
while
    echo "Reading ..."
    read option
    echo "Its MS : $option"
do
    $option
done
```

But is not accepting the command which has space in their arguments.
like **mkdir new\ folder** .

So someone help how to arguments with space..

Comment: perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811033/4256677) will help

Comment: Are you reading commands you want to execute line by line? You could use `set -x` to achieve something very similar.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Simple example please

Comment: See [the manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set): Put `set -x` before the commands you want to see executed and `set +x` after them. *Are* you reading commands from a file?

Comment: @GaneshT : Also, your loop would never terminate (but maybe this is what you want?), becaues you test the exit code of the last `echo` statement, which very likely is `0` always.

Answer (score 0):

For me, your script works just fine.
The problem you describe comes from something else:
Make sure not to use Backslashes for your directories:

Replace `mkdir new\ folder` with `mkdir new/folder`,
that worked for me.

Make also sure not to have a space within the path to your folder:
Not `new /folder`, rather use `new/folder`,
since `mkdir` tries to create two folders if you have that space,
one in the directory `/`, another one in your current directory.

Your code works well,
but for me it fails if I try to plug in sudo commands.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

But i want to create a directory with name **new folder** via that script.

Comment: `
#!/bin/sh

option="mkdir new\\ home"
$option
mkdir new\ home
`
Alternately i want same output for both commands...
What change i should do in  ***option="mkdir new\\ home"*** ?

Comment: About the folder called "new folder": If you want a space in the folder name, you need to use quotation marks in your command: `mkdir "new folder"`, because the terminal splits arguments by spaces. If you use quotation marks, both "new" and "folder" are kept as one token and interpreted as your new folder name.

Comment: @finnmglas : I think GaneshT is about to open a can of worms here. Maybe he also wants to create a directory `$HOME/tmp`, hoping that it should expand `HOME`? In this case, the command should maybe executed via `eval`, though I then wonder why he needs the whole script and does not simply redefine `PS1` and runs a normal shell.