# How to mkdir with a path that has spaces?

Tags: bash

I have a bash beginner problem:
My path to be created is `/Volumes/ADATA\ UFD/Programming/Qt`, where `/Volumes/ADATA\ UFD` exists already. I'd like to write a script in the following form:

```
# create a single output directory 
outputdir="/Volumes/ADATA\ UFD/Programming/Qt"
mkdir -pv $outputdir
```

My problem is that `mkdir` creates the directory `/Volumes/ADATA` and `./UFD/Programming` instead of creating `/Volumes/ADATA\ UFD/Programming/Qt`.

I have looked at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589149/1705967); however, none of these solutions worked:

```
outputdir=/Volumes/"ADATA\ UFD/Programming/Qt"
mkdir -pv $outputdir

outputdir=/Volumes/'ADATA\ UFD/Programming/Qt'
mkdir -pv $outputdir

outputdir='/Volumes/ADATA\ UFD/Programming/Qt'
mkdir -pv $outputdir

outputdir=/Volumes/ADATA' 'UFD/Programming/Qt
mkdir -pv $outputdir
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the good combination here?

Comment: Putting a backslash into a file name is going to cause confusion and grief.  Avoid that at all costs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to quote the variables when you use them. Expanded variables undergo wordsplitting. It's good practice to always quote your expansion, regardless of whether or not you expect it to contain special characters or spaces. You also do not need to escape spaces when quoting.

The following will do what you want:

```
outputdir='/Volumes/ADATA UFD/Programming/Qt'
mkdir -pv "$outputdir"
```

Answer (score 15):

Double quotes around the variable when passed to the `mkdir` command:

```
mkdir -pv "$outputdir"
```

Comment: His variable assignments are also incorrect, as they will result in a literal '\' in the filename.

Comment: Since he says he wants the backslash in the name, he _can_ do it, though he probably _shouldn't_ do it.  I noted that in a comment to the question rather than in my answer, though.