# Can't cd to directory with spaces and hyphen

Tags: ksh

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589149/bash-script-to-cd-to-directory-with-spaces-in-pathname), I made a directory called `Test Directory - 1` and I can't `cd` to it.

I have tried:

- `cd Test\ Directory\ \-\ 1/` (suggested by tab completion)
- `cd "Test Directory - 1"`
- `cd "Test Directory - 1/"`
- `cd 'Test Directory - 1'`
- `cd 'Test Directory - 1/'`
- `cd 'Test Directory \- 1'`

All of these fail and throw the error:

> Usage: cd [-LP] [directory]
>
> Or: cd [ options ] old new

How do I interact with this directory?

Comment: FWIW they all work in bash on OS X...

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is a ksh question.  I'll try bash instead.  **EDIT**: bash worked.  I'm going to leave the question open to get an idea as to why this doesn't work in ksh.

Comment: All (not the last) comands work in my ksh (93u+ 2012-08-01). The last one has `cd: Test Directory \- 1: [No such file or directory]`

Comment: Agree that this should work in `ksh` as well, and that the last item should fail (as it does), becuase of the extra '\' quoting char. Please edit your Q to include output of `echo ${.sh.version); uname -srv` . Check for alias/functions that might be overriding the built-in `alias | grep 'cd ' ; functions | grep 'cp '`. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

What system you are on makes a difference here.
On my Mac, I have no problem with the directory in quote or without quotes:

```
cd Test\ Directory\ -\ 1
```

My understanding is that the spaces are the only characters you have to escape because the shell will split arguments with whitespace. You do not need to escape the - because it has no meaning in the cd shell built-in as it would with say grep.

In general, I would list directories and then process them putting escape characters, i.e. backslash, in front of problematic characters.