# Bash script to change directory from user input

Tags: bash, shell

Whenever I execute this script it says: no such file or directory.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I put quotes around it just in case if there is a space in the directory's name.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter destination: " folder
folder=$(sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' <<< $folder)
cd $folder
```

Comment: Put double-quotes *around* the variable, not *in* the variable. See [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Comment: This may help with your next problem: [Why I can't change directories using “cd”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255414/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use **quotes** in the **cd command**, regardless of whether the directory has spaces or not, like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter destination: " folder
cd "$folder"
pwd
```

Test:

[image]

Another solution (**use with caution as it may cause other problems**) is using **eval** in your code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter destination: " folder
folder=$(sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' <<< $folder)
eval cd $folder
```

References:

- [Bash script to cd to directory with spaces in pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589149/bash-script-to-cd-to-directory-with-spaces-in-pathname)

Comment: Please don't use `eval` like this, it just adds ways for things to go weirdly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, i read this reference ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts ) and I recognize that eval without the corresponding sanitization is evil.